# Fitting 3D ellipsoid to a set of 3D data points

Tags: python, data-fitting

I have set of points whose 3D coordinates are `x`,`y` and `z` and I have to determine the best fit ellipsoid to their distribution.
What makes it difficult is that my points are not distributed on an ellipsoidal surfaces, but they approximately fill the space defined by a cigar.
I usually work with python/C and I know this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find any satisfactory answer.
Do you know how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to find an ellipsoid given the points, or do you want to know how to implement the algorithm in Python?

Comment: Also: what have you tried so far and why did it not work?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an algorithm and I was wondering is somebody already implemented that in python or c.
I could do a least square fitting, but the problem is that my points are not distributed along the surface of the ellipsoid as they fill they entire space. I guess my problem is to find the limiting ellipsoid to a set of points.

Comment: You will probably find something useful if you look for solutions of the minimal [bounding sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere) problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to:
i) take the convex hull of the shape.
ii) take only extremal points (i.e. those lying on the boundary and not inside). 
iii) use a standard ellipsoid fitting algorithm e.g. https://github.com/pierre-weiss/FitEllipsoid.

The main difficulty from what I understood, is that ellipsoid fitting algorithms assume points to be on the boundary. Steps i) and ii) would allow discarding the inside points quite easily.